# How to show dialog when user clicks in a webview dialog

Tags: android, webview

Currently, I have a `WebView` which opens my google drive pdf file which is encrypted (it has a password)

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC6Kx.jpg)

it shows a dialog where I need to input a password,

now my problem is;
Is it possible to set a text in the input?
After the `WebView` retrieve the URL,
is it possible to set a text in the dialog?
thank you.

Comment: provide the code for what you have done in the dialog.,

Comment: i think you can't handle google drive dialog form android side because you have no object or scope to handle google drive dialog